# Linear equation problem (from text)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Tickets to attend a tennis tournament cost  $10,  20$ or $40$. The sales recipe of $10,000$ tickets is $180,000$.

From this information, write the system of equations that would allow you to determine the number of tickets sold in each category.

I have only found the following equation: $10x+20y+40z = 180000$

However, two other equations are missing and I am not able to find them, can you help me please?

Comment: How can you use the number of tickets sold?

Comment: i'm not sure but x+y+z =10000

Comment: @DavidScholz The third "*formula*" is that $x,y,z$ must all be non-negative **integers**.

Comment: Acoording to wolfram $x = 2n, y = 11000 - 3n, z = n - 1000$ for an integer n.

Comment: So, you can't solve it completely, even with $3$ pieces of information.

Comment: not sure to understand the last equation

Comment: What is left for Clement to do is find the range for n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the problem can be simplified by noting that each ticket price is a multiple of 10.  Therefore, you can pretend that the ticket prices have all been divided by 10.

You now have the following three equations:

1. $x + y + z = 10,000.$
2. $x + 2y + 4z = 18,000.$
3. $x,y,z$ are all non-negative integers.

Subtracting (1.) from (2.) above, gives $y + 3z = 8000$.

Since $8000  \equiv 2\pmod{3}$, you know that $y \equiv 2\pmod{3}.$

Further, since $x,y,z$ are all non-negative integers, you know that $y$ must be an element in $S = \{2,5,8, \cdots, 7997, 8000\}.$

If I am not mistaken, each of the $2,667$ possible values of $y$ [re the set S has $2,667$ elements] will yield a (valid) distinct $(x,y,z)$ solution.

---

An alternative formulation is to recognize that $z \in \{0,1,2, \cdots, 2666\},$ and that once $z$ is *chosen*, you have that

- $y = (8000 - 3z).$
- $x = (10,000 - y - z).$